# phpMyAdmin drup_user table does not display all users displayed in Drupal Admin

Tags: drupal

Drupal Admin shows I have about 9000 authenticated users. All spam bots. When I go to phpMyAdmin and look at the drup_users table I see 8 users. When I run the query: SELECT * FROM `drup_users` WHERE `uid` != 1; I see seven. I pretty sure I'm looking at the right db as I only have one. And my Admin user row does match my Drupal Admin information.

What am I missing? Once I get the SELECT to work, I want to change it to: DELETE * FROM `drup_users` WHERE `uid` != 1; to clean out those 9000 users.

Any guidance would be much appreciated! 
(Note: I tried Drupal module "delete all" and I could no longer log in. I looked at Views Bulk Operations and it is way beyond my ability at this point. Hence my db approach.)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Surely the users are in the "users" table, not "drup_users" (which I don't even have in my Drupal installations). Also note that you would have to remove the unwanted users from the "users_roles" table as well.

It sounds like you want to change (in "Config | Account Settings") your installation so that only the administrator can create user accounts, not visitors.

Comment: Many of my drupal fields are prefaced with drup_.  There is no "users" table in my db. I've checked. I've looked at all the fields. drup_roles etc. I can't use that setting for administrator creation. People need to be able to register easily. So where would those 9000 users be stored?